# Excel formula to Power BI formula

Tags: powerbi

How do i write this Excel formula in Power BI ?

```
sumproduct(b5:b20;c5:c20)/sum(c5:c20)
```

In Power BI. I tried the following:

```
Waverage = sumx(table,table[column1])/sum(table[column2])
```

Answer (score 0):

The **SUMPRODUCT** equivalent in PowerBI is **SUMX**, but just need to tweak your formula a bit:

```
Waverage = 
    VAR numerator = SUMX(table,table[column1]*table[column2])
    VAR denominator = SUMX(table, table[column2])
    RETURN DIVIDE(numerator, denominator)
```

The **SUMX** function here loops over each row of the table that you specify and performs calculations based on your expression. Here **SUMX** keeps summing the multiplication *column1* and *column2* row-by-row, until it has done so for all rows.

Variables can be used break down the code into smaller steps for understandability. The **DIVIDE** function is also useful as it automatically deals with instances where the denominator equals zero.